# Android Splash Screen Center Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have an app with a splash screen view that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash2"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVersion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Version "/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lvSplashInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bleh"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPercent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0% of the total"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#9DBA32"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFilename"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="File name: xxxxx"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It renders an image scaled and centered into the screen.  Unfortunately, this isn't working well for us.  It causes a slight flash of white before it loads the view.  My solution was to use an activity style.  That works great, except I can't seem to center AND scale the image.  I can center it easily, but it is wider than the screen.  Here is my xml drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center|bottom|clip_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/splash2"
            />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

How do I scale and center that splash2 image?

Answer (score 12):

You can make the image in Photoshop, put it in the xml then center the whole thing, but I would recommend having a Splash screen while loading the app, because if you have it with a timer it wastes user's time... 
So that's what I did to have a splash screen like this one: [image]

**First**, you have to add a new `Java class`, let's call it `SplashActivity.java`

You don't have to add much to it:

```
package YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**After that**, you have to have a drawable for the splash screen, because if you have a layout it will appear when the app is already loaded, so there won't be any sense in the Splash... 
Go to the `drawable` folder and create a file named `background_splash.xml`.
There you add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center">
<item>
<bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_splash"
        />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

where `ic_splash` is the image I created with Photoshop with resolution 1280x720 and then created a 9-patch image... (You have to have the 9-patch image, not to have normal, small and cropped image on different devices..) So go [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) and generate yours... Create it, download it and copy all the folders (`mdpi, hdpi` etc) to your `res` folder...
**Now,** go to your `values/styles.xml` and add the `NoActionBar` style

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**THEN** open your `Manifest.xml` and edit the activity with `intent-filter`.

Yours should be

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

so replace the `.MainActivity` with `.SplashActivity` and the `.MainActivity` as another activity, so in the end you should have at least **two** activities declared at the `Manifest.xml`:

```
<activity
android:name=".SplashActivity"
android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" or "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </activity>
```

Good luck! :) 
If there are any troubles, ask :)

Comment: How come this answer has no votes!!! This is great. This is the way to go to create a splash screen. Using a theme is the perfect solution as it loads before the layout is even processed to be rendered.